# Random walk high probability

Tags: probability, random-walk

It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk) that a random walk that starts from $0$ and goes $+1$ or $-1$ at each step with equal probability is expected to end within $\pm O(\sqrt{n})$, where $n$ is the number of steps.

Is there a result that says that with probability approaching $1$ as $n$ grows, the random walk will end within $\pm \sqrt{n}$? For example, does it follow from the central limit theorem?

Comment: each increment is independent random variable. and all of them are identical. and random walk is just a sum of iid rvs.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you said is well-known is possibly false, depending on how you define "expected to".

It is actually true that, with probability $1$, the random walk infinitely often goes as far out as $\sqrt{n}\sqrt{\log\log n}$. This fact is known as the [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm).

However, the central limit theorem gives the distribution of $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$. So, for example, the probability that the random walk lies between $-\sqrt{n}$ and $+\sqrt{n}$ is the integral from $-1$ to $1$ of the normal distribution: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-1}^1 e^{-x^2/2}dx \approx .68.$