# Probability of a game never ending

Tags: probability, puzzle, binomial-distribution, probabilistic-method

The game rules are simple. You take one fair coin and flip it. You start counting how many times did you get heads and how many times did you get tails. When the number of tails equal the number of heads, the game finishes. What is the probability that the game carries on forever?

Comment: what have you tried, where are you stuck ?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a well formulated question.  A game can not "go on forever" per se.  Do you mean to ask something else such as "*What is the probability the game requires more than $1000$ throws?  Requires more than $10000$ throws?  Requires more than $N$ throws?*"

Comment: It is well defined. You can just take the limit of what you describe.

Comment: This is a random walk on a line with constant step size. With probability one, it comes back to the origin (infinitely often, if you just keep going).

Comment: Some related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874899/number-of-returns-of-simple-random-walk-until-a-stopping-time and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487268/random-walk-high-probability

Comment: Your "universe" can be placed in bijection with the set of pathes beginning at the origin on the square grid  $\mathbb{N}^2$ made of successive East moves $\binom{1}{0}$ and North moves $\binom{0}{1}$ like EENENEEN...which do not intersect the diagonal line.

Comment: It is almost certain (:)) that the answer is $0$.

Comment: I did not do much work, but I noticed that the number of coins flipped should be pair and that the probability that half the 2n flipped coins will be modelized by a binomial distribution.
P(n when 2n are flipped)=2nCn * (1/n)^2n

Comment: so I said the probability of a game ending at 2n flipped coins is the probability of getting n of them to be head. Therefore the probability of a game not ending would be 1-P (where P is the probability of the game finishing). 
At last i said for a game not to end, it shouldn't end at neither 2n=2;4;6;..
so the probability of a game never ending will be product sum of (1-P)
But that is certainly wrong because in this way the probability of having for example in 4 flipped coins of having 2 heads counts the probability of having those combinations: HTTH, HTHT, HHTT, TTHH, THHT,THTH.

Comment: as you can see the game would end in 4 cases before we flip the coin 4 times, so that's where I am stuck...

Comment: I don't really know how to tag but for jean marie's comment, I have thought about it but I don't really know how I would rigorously write an answer with this proposition

Comment: @Aelkas a point of vocabulary : pair (in french) $\to$ even (in english), impair $\to$ odd.

Comment: I gave you a search term, aelkas, and some links. Did you follow up on any of that?

Comment: Yes, the second might help but it introduces new math theorems that I haven't learned yet

Comment: Here's another link you may wish to follow: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536/proving-that-1-and-2d-simple-symmetric-random-walks-return-to-the-origin-wi Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability is zero, as shown by the following simple argument.

For each $n\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$, let $X_n$ be the quantity (number of heads) - (number of tails) after $n$ flips. WLOG, assume that the first flip is heads, so $X_1=+1$. We will divide the experiment into several "phases" as follows:

- Phase 1 starts at the beginning, and ends the first time that $X_n$ hits either $0$ or $2$. If it exits via $0$, then the experiment is over. Otherwise, phase $2$ starts.
- Phase $2$ ends the first time that $X_n$ hits either $0$ or $4$.
- Phase $3$ ends the first time that $X_n$ hits either $0$ or $8$.
- Phase $4$ ends the first time that $X_n$ hits either $0$ or $16$.
- $\quad\vdots$

The point is, by symmetry, each phase has a $50\%$ chance to end with $X_n=0$, by symmetry, independently of previous phases. The only way for the number of heads to never equal tails is for the this $50\%$ event to never occur after infinitely many attempts, the probability of which is obviously zero.

To be complete, you need to show each phase is almost surely finite. This is not hard to do. For example, phase $4$ ends if at any point there are $16$ heads in a row, so if you divide all of the flips into disjoint blocks of $16$, there will certainly be a block of $16$ heads.